# python type convertion over whole numpy array at once

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy list, type of its element is numpy.float64 and I would like to convert all element of the list to float.

This is the print out of the list:

```
[array([ -7.19244777e+24,   3.32768299e-02,  -7.19249216e+24], dtype=float32), 
 array([ -8.87044985e+25,   1.46775544e-01,  -8.87068228e+25], dtype=float32), 
 array([ 0.61927807, -0.16575921,  0.98002648], dtype=float32),
 array([ 0.63426137, -0.15838303,  0.97730571], dtype=float32)]
```

I could convert each element from numpy.float to float with following code.

```
mtx = []
for i in range(len(centroids)):
    row = []
    for j in range(len(centroids[i])):
        row.append(np.asscalar(centroids[i][j])) 
    mtx.append(row)
```

I am wondering is there any one-liner or utility method to convert elements of whole list from numpy.float64 to float ?

Same question for string and other data types.

Comment: `np.asarray(centroids, dtype=float)`?

Comment: I fear the cause of this in the first place is that your lists are ragged (not equal sized in length), unless these are all the arrays you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.ndarray.tolist()` does precisely what you want.

```
>>> a = np.identity(3, np.float64)
>>> a
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
>>> a.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> b = a.tolist()
>>> type(b[0][0])
<class 'float'>
```

Applied to your list of arrays:

```
>>> array = np.array
>>> float32 = np.float32
>>> loa = [array([ -7.19244777e+24,   3.32768299e-02,  -7.19249216e+24], dtype=float32), 
...  array([ -8.87044985e+25,   1.46775544e-01,  -8.87068228e+25], dtype=float32), 
...  array([ 0.61927807, -0.16575921,  0.98002648], dtype=float32),
...  array([ 0.63426137, -0.15838303,  0.97730571], dtype=float32)]
>>> 
>>> lol = [a.tolist() for a in loa]
>>> lol
[[-7.192447772100603e+24, 0.03327682986855507, -7.19249215957853e+24], [-8.870449851573768e+25, 0.14677554368972778, -8.870682280549097e+25], [0.619278073310852, -0.16575920581817627, 0.9800264835357666], [0.6342613697052002, -0.15838302671909332, 0.9773057103157043]]
>>> type(lol[0][0])
<class 'float'>
```